# Passcode lock for WhatsApp

Tags: ios

I am using an iPod touch 5 and I want to put a password on my WhatsApp, but the apps available on the App Store are not according to my need. Can you suggest some apps so that I can put a passcode on WhatsApp without jailbreaking?

Comment: Put a passcode on your iPhone?

Comment: Just lock it with a passcode pal... and if you have a nosy girlfriend.. just leave her

Answer (score 3):

Individual apps from the App Store can't be passcode protected in this way without jailbreaking which you mentioned you don't want to do. Restrictions are only available for pre-installed apps and features.

Instead, you can passcode the device, which will prevent access to the apps on the device, including WhatsApp. Go to Settings → Passcode to set it up.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I used my login code both for my iphone 5 and my ipad and it worked fine. This is if you have downloaded the update and it asks you for a code and gives you a square for 4 letters. This is where you put in your log on code.